# Structure of an Optimal Solution to a Fractional Packing Problem

Tags: linear-programming

**Packing LP**

We have the following optimization problem:

$$ \max_{x_{ij}} x_{ij} c_{ij}$$
s.t. $$(i)\forall j\mbox{ }\sum_{i} x_{ij} \leq \beta_j$$
$$(ii)\forall i\mbox{ }\sum_{j} x_{ij} D_{ij} \leq 1$$
$$(iii)\forall i\mbox{ }\forall j\mbox{ }0 \leq  x_{ij} \leq 1.$$

Here, $D_{ij} \geq 1$ are integers, $c_{ij} \geq 0$, $\beta_j>0$, and $\sum_j \beta_j  = 1$.

*Are there known results to understand the structure of the optimal solution of the above LP?*

**Connection to Generalized Flow Problem:**

This packing problem can be formed as a generalized max cost flow problem on a graph which has one source and one sink. The flow passes through a complete bipartite graph.

The nodes in left partite are connected to the source and correspond to the $i$-component in the LP. The edge between the source and the $i$-th node has: (cost = 0, capacity = 1, scale = 1).

The nodes in right partite are connected to the sink and correspond to the $j$-component in the LP. The edge between the source and the $i$-th node has (cost = 0, capacity = $\beta_j$, scale = 1).

In the bipartite graph, the edge $i\to j$ have:
(cost = $c_{ij}$, capacity  = $1$, scale = $1/D_{ij}$).

*Can this be used to infer any structure for the optimal solution?*

Crossposted:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/44494/structure-of-an-optimal-solution-to-a-fractional-packing-problem